# how to stop reading from file in C

Tags: c, stdio

I am just trying to read each character of the file and print it out but when the file finishes reading, but I am getting a bunch of ? after it finishes reading. How do I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fr;            /* declare the file pointer */

    fr = fopen ("some.txt", "r");  /* open the file for reading */
        /* elapsed.dta is the name of the file */
        /* "rt" means open the file for reading text */
    char c;
    while((c = getc(fr)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(fr);  /* close the file prior to exiting the routine */
    /*of main*/ 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with all warnings enabled? I have a feeling your while loop conditional is the problem, but I'm not sure. If it's what I'm thinking it might be, a warning will come up if you compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: Everything you need to know about FILE is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/FILE/

Comment: You should be more careful about the return type of `getc()`, and also realize that `NULL` is a pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In spite of its name, `getc` returns an `int`, not a `char`, so that it can represent all of the possible char values and, in addition, `EOF` (end of file). If `getc` returned a `char`, there would be no way to indicate the end of file without using one of the values that could possibly be in the file.

So, to fix your code, you must first change the declaration `char c;` to `int c;` so that it can hold the EOF marker when it is returned. Then, you must also change the while loop condition to check for `EOF` instead of `NULL`.

You could also call `feof(fr)` to test end of file separately from reading the character. If you did that, you could leave `c` as a `char`, but you would have to call `feof()` after you read the character but before you printed it out, and use a `break` to get out of the loop.

Comment: Nit: in C, plain `char` can be signed or unsigned.  Your statement above is true when `char` is unsigned, but if `char` is signed, it *may* be able to represent `EOF`.  Typically, `EOF` is a small negative constant (-1 for example), and that's easily represented in a `signed char`.

Comment: Exactly.  The only way to reliably and portably test for EOF is by using `feof`.

Comment: @Alok: I don't see what it has to do with `char` itself being signed or not; `getc` returns the character as an `unsigned char` converted to `int`.  You indeed would have the `EOF` collision if `sizeof(int) == 1`, however.

Comment: @jamesdlin: If a char is unsigned, it can never be equal to `-1`, but if it is signed, then it *can* be equal to `-1`, and therefore be equal to `EOF`.

Comment: @myself: this of course assumes that EOF is -1, but the same would hold true if EOF was any negative integer greater than -129.

Comment: @dreamlax: Yes, a signed char can equal `EOF`, but we're talking about the value returned by `getc`, aren't we? `getc` does not sign-extend the `char` it stuffs into the returned `int`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: No, we're talking about `benzado`'s statement regarding the use of `int` to represent all `char` values and in addition representing `EOF`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: if `getc` detects the end-of-file condition, it returns -1 *without* interpreting it as an `unsigned char`.  It doesn't make sense for `getc` to do an `unsigned char` conversion at the end of file.  From the standard: *If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` ...* (n1336, 7.19.7.1).  In any case, my point was that `EOF` may be in the range [`CHAR_MIN`, `CHAR_MAX`].

Comment: We're all in agreement.  Sorry.  I simply misunderstood what "Your statement above" was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

If unsuccessful, `fgetc()` returns EOF.

```
int c;
while ((c = getc(fr)) != EOF) 
{ 
    printf("%c", c); 
}
```

Comment: c needs to be declared as an int as well.

Comment: @Emerick Rogul: do you want that comment under the original question?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
char c;
while((c = getc(fr)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

to

```
char c;
int charAsInt;
while((charAsInt = getc(fr)) != EOF)
{
     c = (char) charAsInt;
     printf("%c", c);
}
```

In other words: You need to compare against `EOF`, not `NULL`. You also need to use an `int` variable to receive the return value from `fgetc`. If you use a `char`, the comparison with `EOF` may fail, and you'll be back where you started.

Comment: Many other functions expect type `int` even though they typically only operate within the range of `char`. `putchar`, `isdigit`, `strchr` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`fgetc()` returns `EOF` on end-of-file, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "NULL" with "EOF".

Answer (score 1):

Others have already addressed the issue you're having, but rather than using `printf("%c", c);` it is probably much more efficient to use `putchar(c);`. There is quite a bit of overhead involved when you ask `printf` to print just one character.

Comment: True, but the same holds for using `fgetc` instead of `fgets` or `fscanf`.

Comment: Also, SuperString is trying to learn C. The infinitesimal amount of overhead is not important at this point, and learning how to use printf is more useful in general than putchar. Since this isn't an answer to the question, you should have left a comment.

Comment: Using `getc` with `putchar` makes more sense since one is intended to read one character from `stdin`, and the other is intended to output one character to `stdout`.

Comment: Even if efficiency were a concern (which it's not), this program would definitely be I/O-bound, not CPU-bound, so the difference between `printf` and `putchar` is negligibl.

Comment: Sorry, before I mentioned `getc` gets a character from `stdin`, but I meant to say it gets a character from a from a stream.

Comment: Yes you're quite right. However, I still think `putchar` is a better choice of function given the situation.

Answer (score 1):

**getc** returns an **int**.

change **char c**, to **int c**.

also **getc** returns **EOF**,
change your test against **NULL** to a test against **EOF**